# Reusable react component tools

Tags: reactjs, components

Besides

- bitsrc: (which is nice, but painful to figure out with lack of docs)
- verdaccio: private npm repo
- opencomponent

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a [Bit](https://github.com/teambit/bit) maintainer.

To simplify, here's how Bit works:

1. Use Bit to share the components from the local repo to bitsrc.io (no refactoring).
2. Organize, share and explore in bitsrc.io
3. Install in other projects (npm/yarn/bit)

On Feb 4th we released a very large version fixing 70% of issues (adding new features to bitsrc.io, 700% performance upgrade).

So, I'd suggest [you try it](https://bitsrc.io/components) now and if you need any help we'd love to help you on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/bit-src/Bit).

Cheers